# How to prevent combining CSS rules when building with Parcel bundler?

Tags: css, css-selectors, parceljs

I'm using the Parcel bunder and I have some CSS that uses `:focus-visible` and its polyfill like this:

```
/* Keyboard focus for all elements. */
:focus {
  z-index: 1;
  outline: medium dotted black;
}

/* Remove mouse focus if :focus-visible is supported. */
:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}

/* Polyfill for :focus-visible. */
.js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}
```

My reasoning is that if `:focus-visible` is supported, the second rule will run regardless of whether the polyfill is loaded or not. If `:focus-visible` is not supported, the second rule is ignored but the third rule will run.

When I build with `parcel build src/index.html`, the compiled CSS file has a combined rule like this:

```
.js-focus-visible :focus:not(.focus-visible),:focus:not(:focus-visible){outline:none}
```

So it combines the second and third rules into one. The problem is now this entire rule is ignored by browsers that do not support `:focus-visible`. What's the recommended way to solve this sort of problem?